# Is it possible to clone only certain commit from a git repo with depth 1?

Tags: git, pip, git-clone

`pip` package manager allows [installing from various VCS](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirement-format.html) including `git`:

> Pip currently supports cloning over git, git+http and git+ssh:
>
> ```
> -e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git#egg=MyProject
> -e git+http://git.myproject.org/MyProject/#egg=MyProject
> -e git+ssh://git@myproject.org/MyProject/#egg=MyProject
> ```
>
> Passing branch names, a commit hash or a tag name is also possible:
>
> ```
> -e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject
> -e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@v1.0#egg=MyProject
> -e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#egg=MyProject
> ```

This is nice when the package is small, however, it becomes quite slow when the package is huge (e.g. Django). If I need just the last commit of master branch, then I could use `--depth 1` parameter for git clone.

Is it possible to get only a certain commit without the full repo history in general? At least from github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can neither `clone` nor `fetch` from remote a particular commit, much less a depth of 1, due to security reasons: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/73368/focus=73994

http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fetch-by-SHA-missing-td5604552.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I can get a tarball for a particular commit/branch/tag instead, e.g. `mkdir src ; curl https://nodeload.github.com/django/django/tarball/1.3 | tar xz --directory=./src` and then install from the dir `pip install src/django-django-*`

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no. You may want to ask about this on the [git mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub API to get last/any commit: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit

It's not a git command, you'll need to make a HTTP request, parse JSON response and download files with diff-data.